# Variational Monte Carlo for 1-d harmonic oscillator

Tags: python, algorithm, physics

Here's a code that I wrote to find the ground state energy of an harmonic oscillator. To avoid round-off error and so I wrote the schrodinger equation in Atomic system unit:

H= -d2/dx2 + 1/2x^2

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
from random import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Nwalker=300;MCSteps=5000
x=[0]*Nwalker
nAccept=0;eSum=0
Lambda=0.2

# Define Building Block Functions
    # 1.Initialize function, for setting random walkers' initial positions
    # 2.Probability function, allowing acceptance or rejection
    # 3.MetropolisStep function, 
    # 4.oneMonteCarloStep function, performing Nwalker MetopolisSteps

#.......................START.....................
#.................................................

def initialize():

    for i in range(Nwalker):
        x[i]=random()-0.5

def p(xTrial,x):

    # compute the ratio of rho(xTrial) / rho(x)
    return np.exp(-2*Lambda*(xTrial**2-x**2))

def eLocal(x):

    # compute the local energy
    return Lambda + x**2*(0.5-2*Lambda**2)

def MetropolisStep():

    global eSum,nAccept
    # chose a walker at random
    n=int(random()*Nwalker)
    # make a trial move
    delta=0.05*(random()-1)
    xTrial=x[n]+delta

    # Metropolis test
    w=p(xTrial,x[n])

    if w>=random():
        x[n]=xTrial
        nAccept+=1

    # accumulate energy
    e=eLocal(x[n])
    eSum+=e

def oneMonteCarloStep():
   # perform 'Nwalker' Metropolis steps
   for i in range(Nwalker):
       MetropolisStep()

#...............................................
#.....................END.......................


initialize()

# perform 20% of MCSteps as thermalization steps

thermSteps=int(0.2*MCSteps)
print('Performing', thermSteps,'thermalization steps ...')

for i in range(thermSteps):
    oneMonteCarloStep()

# production steps

print('Performing',MCSteps,'production steps ...')  
nAccept=0;eSum=0

for i in range(MCSteps):
    oneMonteCarloStep()             

# compute and print energy
eAve=eSum/(Nwalker*MCSteps)

print(eAve)             
print(nAccept/(Nwalker*MCSteps))
```

I actually followed the algorithm suggested by this website. http://www.physics.buffalo.edu/phy411-506/topic5/

For Lambda=0.5, I get =0.5, which is perfectly fine. But for other values of Lambda I get very strange values for mean energy. As you see the right plot for mean energy versus Lambda is shown in the linked article.

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with my code? The code seems to be almost like the code written in the article. Don't know why it doesn't work.

Added picture...

[image]

Comment: Post the relevant plot here. I shouldn't have to go offsite to answer your question.

Comment: You don't appear to be applying any of the calculations during the thermalization steps to adjust the delta as shown in the linked code. Instead you compute the delta randomly each metropolis step. Can you explain the difference?